# Dividing html file content into several parts on user button click using javascript and css on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have an html file that I want to display part of it according to some height value and then when user clicks on button next it will show the rest of the html file and so on. Same behavior as when a user flips pages of a book. How can I do that on IE browser using javascript and css over html file? Is there any available example?

Comment: Have you searched before asking? What have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: I have tried to use window.scrollBy.

Comment: window.scrollBy(-(myWidth + myGap), 0); and window.scrollBy(myWidth + myGap, 0); for the other direction where mywidth and mygap are static values. But it doesn't always work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you are looking for this:

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Those 'parts' of html are tab content, and 'button' to flip are tab controls.

But if you want use same button to flip, you'll need to manually call tab switch when button clicked.